# How to recreate page references in LibreOffice

Tags: reference, libreoffice, generated-code

Before you dismiss this post as using LibreOffice documents THE WRONG WAY, let me explain what I'm trying to achieve. I am generating programatically ODT documents, which is mostly no big deal. I have hit the wall, however, trying to insert internal references into the documnt. It's quite simple to include an anchor in the `content.xml` with:

```
<text:reference-mark text:name="anchor"/>
```

inside `<text:p>` element. But when you want to reference it later LibreOffice inserts a reference with the page number. Obviously I don't know the page number where the anchor is, but I can easily include a reference to the anchor with

```
<text:reference-ref text:reference-format="page" text:ref-name="anchor"/>
```

The question is how to make LibreOffice recreate and insert page number on reading the document?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that LibreOffice does recreate page numbers provided there is actually any number included as contents of `text:reference-ref`

```
<text:reference-ref text:reference-format="page" text:ref-name="anchor">1</text:reference-ref>
```

When opened, upon a change of the file the page number is updated by LibreOffice.